# How to write the sql to findout which value is not in the table?

Tags: sql

I am having a table Student and i have a set of 20 names.

by using his sql

```
select name from student st where st.name in (
 'abc', 'xyz', . . .
)
```

i can find out all student names which are in table and in the set.
Now, how can i find out which out of these 20 names are not in Student table.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you want the names themselves.
One option is to create a table with all the available student names, then select from it rows which don't have corresponding rows in the student tables, it will look something like this
`select name from student_names

where name not in (select name from students)`

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE student(name VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO student VALUES('a'), ('abc');
CREATE TABLE temp(x VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO temp VALUES('abc'), ('xyz');
SELECT x FROM temp WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM student st WHERE st.name = x);
```

Depending on the database you use, there might be an easier way. There is also a way using UNION.

Comment: This is a bit neater than my solution. I didn't know about the `VALUES('abc'), ('xyz')` syntax so +1 for that alone. Depending on the database, this could probably be a table variable rather than a temporary physical table.

Comment: Some databases support easier (non-standard) ways, for example the H2 database supports: SELECT temp.x FROM TABLE(x VARCHAR = ('abc', 'xyz')) temp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM student st WHERE st.name = x); Disclaimer: I implemented this extension in H2.

Comment: Actually the VALUES('abc'), ('xyz') syntax doesn't work in all databases (yet). Which is unfortunate.

Comment: can't we do that without creating another table. Or if possible using temp table.

Comment: Yes, you can use a temporary table. But unfortunately, not all databases do support temporary tables. If you tell us what database you use we can provide a 'custom' solution. I know SQL is supposed to be a standard.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT NOT IN ?

postgresql: http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-sql/2002-08/msg00322.php

Answer (score 0):

```
select name from student where name not in (
select name from student st where st.name in (
 'abc', 'xyz', . . .
))
```

**EDIT: I might not get what you are looking for. Please run following script and it is giving the results.**

```
declare @student table
(
    name varchar(50)
)

insert into @student select 'james'
insert into @student select 'will'
insert into @student select 'bill'
insert into @student select 'adam'
insert into @student select 'jon'
insert into @student select 'white'
insert into @student select 'green'

select name from @student where name in ('james', 'will', 'bill')

select name from @student where name not in (select name from @student where name in ('james', 'will', 'bill'))
```

Comment: this is not giving desired results

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @names table ( name varchar(100) )
INSERT INTO @names VALUES ('abc')
...
INSERT INTO @names VALUES ('xyz')

SELECT name FROM @names WHERE name NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM Student )
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the tool you are using can generate dynamic sql, try generating an inline view consisting of your set of user names - like so:

```
select 'abc' check_name union all
select 'xyz' check_name union all
```

...

(The syntax of the inline view may depend on which version of SQL you are using - some versions of SQL require a `from [dummy_table]` clause in select statements that are not accessing a table.)

Then construct a query using this inline view with a not exists in student clause, like this:

```
select check_name from (
select 'abc' check_name union all
select 'xyz' check_name union all
```

...

```
) ilv where not exists
(select null from student st where st.name = ilv.check_name)
```